# Error in unity(Script Inspector 3): GetBool is not allowed to be called from a ScriptableObject constructor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
GetBool is not allowed to be called from a ScriptableObject constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in OnEnable instead. Called from ScriptableObject 'FGConsole'.
See "Script Serialization" page in the Unity Manual for further details.
UnityEditor.EditorPrefs:GetBool(String, Boolean)
ScriptInspector.FGConsole:.cctor() (at Assets/Plugins/Editor/ScriptInspector3/Scripts/FGConsole.cs:65)
```

I have a error in unity after using Script Inspector 3 in unity as an assets.
The above error shows in console which does not let me to attach scripts to Game Objects and compile my error.
How to remove this error?

Comment: I suppose I'd try to remove the GetBool method from the ScriptableObject constructor, hehe. Have you written any classes that derive from ScriptableObject? In that constructor, you're not allowed to use GetBool, it seems. Show us the code around FGConsole.cs, line 65, which is where the exception is pointing to. Otherwise I'm guessing there's a bug in Script Inpsector 3.

Comment: These scripts are all defaults so i don't know what should i do?

Comment: static FGConsole()
 {
  _openLogEntriesInSi2 = EditorPrefs.GetBool("ScriptInspector.OpenLogEntriesInSi2", true);
  consoleWindowType = typeof(EditorWindow).Assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.ConsoleWindow");
  .......

Comment: Try just setting it to true instead? Or false, ehatever you see fit. Contact the creator of the script/asset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Niresh, the version of Script Inspector 3 you are using is way too old for newer versions of Unity. In July 2016 Unity released version 5.4 and Script Inspector 3 got upgraded to version 3.0.13 to support those changes. Just update your copy from Unity Asset Store to the latest released Si3 version (currently 3.0.17) and it will just work fine.